# Looking for references on this system of linear PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I was looking for references on the following PDEs:
$$
u_t + a u_x - w_{xx} = f \\
w_t + a w_x -u =g \\
u(x,0)=u_0(x), \ w(x,0)=w_0(x) 
$$
where $f\in C([0,T];H^s(\mathbb{R}))$; $a,g\in C([0,T];H^{s+1}(\mathbb{R}))$;
$u_0\in H^s(\mathbb{R})$; $w_0\in H^{s+1}(\mathbb{R})$. Both $u$ and $w$ are scalar functions. The index $s\geq 3$.

I was wondering how should we prove the existence and uniqueness of solutions $u\in C([0,T];H^{s}(\mathbb{R}))$ and $w\in C([0,T];H^{s+1}(\mathbb{R}))$?

I'd appreciate it a lot for any advice! Thank you very much!

Comment: Let $u = v_{x}$ to get

\begin{align}
v_{xt} + a v_{xx} - w_{xx} = f \implies v_{t} + a v_{x} - w_{x} &= F \\
w_{t} + a w_{x} - v_{x} &= g
\end{align}

with $F' = f$, which can then be solved using the method of characteristics, either by [diagonalising the system](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3666725/help-solving-shallow-water-equations-initial-value-problem/3667446#3667446) or by adding the two equations together directly and defining $z = v + w$.

Comment: Thank you very much! @MatthewCassell