# How do I solve this coupled PDEs?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences

I am trying to solve the following coupled system:

$$
\left\{\begin{aligned}
U_t + \lambda_1 U_x &= 0 \\
V_t - \lambda_2 V_x &= c(x) U(x,t) \\
U(0,t) + k_{0} V(0,t) &= 0 \\
V(L,t) - k U(L,t) &= 0
\end{aligned}\right.
$$

where $\lambda_{1} = 70, \lambda_{2} = 20, c(x) = - 24e^{-12x/35}, k_{0} = 2/7$ and $k=e^{-12/35}$.

I would like to discretize these coupled PDEs and I tried writing out using finite difference methods, but how do I deal with $U(x,t)$ on the right side of the second-line equation of the system?

Comment: The PDE in $U$ is decoupled from $V$ so solve that equation first and then solve the problem in $V$ which, as you know the exact form of $U$, is just a first order, inhomogeneous, linear PDE.

Comment: @MatthewCassell Oh, it explains the matter. Thank you very much! But if the right side of the first equation is V(x,t), then how do I solve it?

Comment: You solve it the same way both times, using the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics). However, when there is a dependence on $V$ on the right hand side of the equation in $U$, you would usually try to diagonalise the system in the same manner as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3666725/help-solving-shallow-water-equations-initial-value-problem/3667446#3667446) though I believe that this can be quite difficult as the right hand side of the system will be dependent on $(V, U)$ and not derivatives of. Give it a try, see how it goes.